# Networkx - Shortest path length

Tags: python, networkx

I'm  using `networkx` to manage large network graph which consists of 50k nodes.

I want to calculate the shortest path length between a specific set of nodes, say N.
For that i'm using the `nx.shortest_path_length` function.

In some of the nodes from N there might not be a path so networkx is raising and stopping my program.

Is there any way to run this program without any error?
And to tell to `shortest_path_length` to return some maximum value?

Code simply uses `nx.shortest_path_length(G,i,j)`in loop.
and error is as follows

`raise nx.NetworkXNoPath("No path between %s and %s." % (source, target))
networkx.exception.NetworkXNoPath: No path between V and J`

Comment: "and stopping my program"?  Do you mean it raises an Exception?  Are you asking for help with the `try:` statement?  Can you post code and the actual error message you're actually getting?

Comment: Yeah it is raising exception and there is run time error so it prints exception message in output and doesn't even process other nodes in iteration.

Comment: The comment isn't help.  Actually **update** the question with code and details of the exception.  And -- if you are unfamiliar with the try statement, find a tutorial and ask **specific** questions about the try statement after doing the tutorial.

Comment: Please.  Actually **update** the question with code and details of the exception.  Comments are hard to read.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @ThomasK it'll display proper error message but i want networkx to return some large value if there is no path.

Comment: networkx won't return it, but you can set the variable to a large number in the `except` clause instead.

Comment: you can user `has_path(G, source, target)` function. more doc: http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.has_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.has_path

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4])
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(3,4)
try:
    n=nx.shortest_path_length(G,1,4)
    print n
except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
    print 'No path'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, depending on the type of graph--namely, **directed**, strongly or weakly connected, or **undirected**--create component subgraphs (sub_G), that is,

`(G.subgraph(c) for c in connected_components(G))`

or if **directed:**

`nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(G)` or
  `nx.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs(G)`

Furthermore, given sub_G is a directed graph, check for the strength of its connections, e.g.

`nx.is_strongly_connected(sub_G)` or
  `ng.is_weakly_connected(sub_G)`

Combined or individually, these recommendations'll reduce unnecessary checking of paths that do not exist due to the nature of the component subgraph(s).