# Source algorithm for networkx shortest_path(G[, source, target, weight]) function

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx, shortest-path

I am doing some work with networkx and have used two shortest path algoritms namely:

```
 shortest_path(G[, source, target, weight]) 
 dijkstra_path(G, source, target[, weight])
```

I understand that the  `dijkstra_path(G, source, target[, weight])` function is based on the dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. I would like to know the source algorithm upon which the `shortest_path(G[, source, target, weight])` function is based. I need it because I have to report about the algorithms I have used. I have searched some stackoverflow pages like [Networkx - Shortest path length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430027/networkx-shortest-path-length) and
[All shortest paths for weighted graphs with networkx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550292/all-shortest-paths-for-weighted-graphs-with-networkx) but they don't quite answer my question, I have also look closely at the networkx documentation and other articles on google and haven't gotten found an answer. Can someone please help me with this information. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a breadth-first search algorithm (BFS).  Here is the entire NetworkX code for the single-source problem.  It is also used for the all-pairs shortest path calculation.  For source-target shortest path a bidirectional version of BFS is used.  This isn't very well documented but the document and code is here at http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html

```
def single_source_shortest_path(G,source,cutoff=None):
    level=0                  # the current level
    nextlevel={source:1}       # list of nodes to check at next level
    paths={source:[source]}  # paths dictionary  (paths to key from source)
    if cutoff==0:
        return paths
    while nextlevel:
        thislevel=nextlevel
        nextlevel={}
        for v in thislevel:
            for w in G[v]:
                if w not in paths:
                    paths[w]=paths[v]+[w]
                    nextlevel[w]=1
        level=level+1
        if (cutoff is not None and cutoff <= level):  break
    return paths
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I guess the keyword I needed is BFS. That will enable me research that further. I appreciate

Answer (score 2):

This also runs Dijkstra for the "typical" case, look at the source, which shows that it is just some conditional clauses:

http://networkx.lanl.gov/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/generic.html#shortest_path

```
 ...
 if source is None:
        if target is None:
            if weight is None:
                paths=nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)
            else:
                paths=nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G,weight=weight)
        else:
            raise nx.NetworkXError(\
                "Target given but no source specified.")
    else: # source specified
        if target is None:
            if weight is None:
                paths=nx.single_source_shortest_path(G,source)
            else:
                paths=nx.single_source_dijkstra_path(G,source,weight=weight)
        else:
            # shortest source-target path
            if weight is None:
                paths=nx.bidirectional_shortest_path(G,source,target)
            else:
                paths=nx.dijkstra_path(G,source,target,weight)

    return paths
```